# Implementing Timer in Android See code below for assistance

Tags: java, android, timer

Hello everyone I have my MathQuestions Class and i want the timer to start once the play button in MainActivity is pressed `(onClickStart)`. I am having difficulties in knowing were to start the timer. Any help offered will be appreciated. I have written down what i want done in the GameTimer class with my ImageButton and TextView but I have tried several ways with no luck. The app keeps closing.

my Code where the MathQuestion class is started.

This is my play button;

```
 public void onClickStart(View view){

            EditText nameInput = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.playerName);
            name = nameInput.getText().toString();
        Intent i = new Intent(this,MathQuestions.class);
                    i.putExtra("levelSelected", Integer.valueOf(radiobutton));
                    startActivity(i);
```

My math_layout xml which is used in both MathQuestion and GameTimer
This is the pause imagebutton and the `OnTick TextView`

```
<ImageButton
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_pause_white_18dp"
        android:background="@drawable/circle"
        android:id="@+id/pause"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:onClick="pause"
        android:layout_below="@+id/questionField"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/ontick"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="#FF0000"
        android:elevation="5dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

The Error;

```
onTick(GameTimer.java:48)
            at android.os.CountDownTimer$1.handleMessage(CountDownTimer.java:133)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
```

Comment: What is your actual issue? You already starting the countdown in onCreate and where is play button in the whole scene?...

Comment: I have added it on the question.

Comment: `GameTimer timer = new GameTimer();`. no. you can't instanciate activities yourself.

Comment: Actually i have included it there wrongly, i know that is not right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you are trying to modify the view from background thread which is the overrided method of CountdownTimer.

Try to update your view like this from background thread. eg:-

```
text.post(new Runnable(){
     @Override
     Public void run(){
         text.setText("set your text");
    }
});
```

Comment: which text exactly? you mean my tick? I think that is where i have issues.

Comment: This is just an example. For your case the text view changes you are doing inside the onTick and onFinish module of CountdownTimer. You should do it like the given example.

Comment: Post is a method supported by all views in android. And it's purpose it to perform the ui changes in the main thread.

Comment: Most welcome....but the better way of saying thanks on this portal is to vote up the answer....lolzzzz ;-)

Comment: Definitely i will dont worry, I need to put it in the code first dont worry. :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87629/discussion-between-mia-and-eej).